# Opscode Chef for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-recipe

I am new to opscode chef. I want to integrate opscode chef in my web application. I have created a node using the [web console](https://manage.opscode.com/) of opscode on  Amazon EC2. Now I want to know that what to do and how to play with cookbooks and other part of chef? I am also unable to connect with the instance i have created on Amazon EC2. I am using the hosted chef server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After working on Opscode Chef I have found an answer for my question. So, let it be share.
The full documentation is available in the [Chef Wiki](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home), which features dedicated guides for various special topics as well, e.g.:

- [EC2 Bootstrap Fast Start Guide](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/EC2+Bootstrap+Fast+Start+Guide)
- [Fast Start Guide for Windows](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Fast+Start+Guide+for+Windows)
- [Fast Start Guide for Ubuntu](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Fast+Start+Guide)
- [Fast Start Guide for CentOS](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Fast+Start+Guide+for+CentOS)

Comment: I want to install enterprise chef, but i dont have any direction where to head

Comment: Above links will help you to do that.